# Actualizar los subnodes de un Tree Store- ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Antes de todo soy nuevo en el EXT JS y os pido perdón de antemano si no me explico con claridad.

LLevo unos cuantos días con este problema y como no he encontrado nada por internet que pueda ayudarme he decidido preguntar a ver si me podeís ayudar.

Mi problema es que tengo un tree store compuesto por los nodes principales (padres) y a su vez estos tienen sus hijos (hijos) y cuando recargo el tree store no me actualiza los hijos, es decir, si elimino un hijo o añado uno éste no desaparece o aparece del menú. Averigué que hay una configuración del tree store llamada "clearOnLoad", que  por defecto es true, que elimina por completo los nodos del tree store y los vuelve a meter, pero yo no quiero que haga eso. Ahora lo tengo en false pero es el problema que os estoy planteando. Quiero añadir que los padres si me los actualiza bien.

Mi código:

```
App.mainmenu = new Ext.tree.Panel({
    region: "west",
    width: 190,
    collapsible:true,
    split: false,
    border: true,
    title:"Main Menu",
    useArrows: true,
    rootVisible: false,
    store: new Ext.data.TreeStore({
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            api: {
                read : 'service.php/main_tree.tree?session_token='+sessionStorage.getItem("session_token")+'&ll_token='+sessionStorage.getItem("ll_token"),
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'children',
                successProperty: 'success',
                idProperty: 'id',
            },
        },
        root: {
            expanded: true
        },
        clearOnLoad: false, //por defecto es true
        cleanRecords: function(node,records) {
          return records;
        },
        fillNode: function(node, newNodes) {
          //Check the ones that are left over on the tree_store
          for (var i in node.childNodes) {
            var found = false;
            for (var x in newNodes) {
              if (node.childNodes[i].raw.text == newNodes[x].raw.text) {
                found = true;
                break;
              }
            }
            if (!found) {
              node.removeChild(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
          }
          //Check the ones that are missing on the tree_store
          for (var x in newNodes) {
            var child = node.findChildBy(function(record) {
              if (record.raw.text == newNodes[x].raw.text) {
                return true;
              } else {
                return false;
              }
            });
            if (child === null) {
              node.insertChild (x,newNodes[x]);
            }
          }
        }
    }),
    listeners: {
        scope: this,
        itemclick: function(view, record) {
            data = (record.raw ? record.raw : record.data);
            if (data.app_name) {
              App[data.app_name](data.config || null);
              return;
            }
            (data).handler(data.config || null);
        }
    }
});
```

La estructura del árbol es este:

[image: Estructura del árbol]

Pueden tener más hijos, eso es un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

```
          //Check the ones that are missing on the tree_store
      for (var x in newNodes) {
        var child = node.findChildBy(function(record) {
          if (record.raw.text == newNodes[x].raw.text) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        });
        if (child === null) {
          node.insertChild (x,newNodes[x]);
        } else {
          if(typeof(newNodes[x].raw.children)!=="undefined" ){
            child.raw.children = newNodes[x].raw.children;
            this.tree.fireEvent('append', node, child);
          }
        }
      }
      return newNodes;
    }
}),
```

He usado el fireevent append y me funciona, es decir, que ya me actualiza los hijos como quiero. Espero que mi solución os sirva como a mi. :D

Me disculpo si este tema no quedó muy claro, oajalá entendiese más sobre Ext Js para poder explicar mejor las cosas.